# ActiveRecord callback on when object has updated virtual attribute NOT in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

CODE

```
# Item Model
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :paid_amount
  after_save :amount_processed?

  def amount_processed?
    if self.try(:paid_amount)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end

# Controller snippet
...
# params = {"paid_amount" => 10}
@item.assign_attributes(params)
if @item.valid?
  @item.save
end
...
```

Currently the callback is not running, i.e., the code never checks `amount_processed?`. The reason this is happening is because `paid_amount` isn't a db attribute for `Item`. But that is by design. The question is ASSUMING this design were to stay, would there be a way for me to run a callback to check `amount_processed?` simply based on the fact that the attribute was passed? (i.e., if you run `@item.paid_amount` you'd get `"10"` after the `@item.assign_attributes`).

Note that the following callbacks will not work:

- `after_save` or `after_touch` because as above, the `paid_amount` is never saved so the `@item` is never updated
- `after_find` because this runs, by definition, before the attribute assignment. So with this validation, even though `amount_processed?` is checked, when it is checked, `@item.paid_amount = nil`

Would love to combine the two...

Since the question asks how to do this GIVEN current design, a perfectly acceptable answer is to say in the current design, it's not possible. The callback will only work if the attribute is actually updated. In that case, I already have 2 strategies to tackle this, the easiest of which being moving `amount_processed?` to the controller level so I can check the `paid_amount` after the `assign_attributes`. The other strategy is to have a Child of Item, but this is dependent on other info about the code that, for simplicity's sake, I have withheld.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `validate :amount_processed?`. See [custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods)

Comment: Pretty sure your code should work just fine.  Are you sure that (a) params contains what you think it does and (b) the entity is actually valid?  If you are getting `params` straight form a form or something, I would think you would need to grab the values from `params[:item]`  `afterSave` is merely a callback, it's independent of any variable.  You could just grab the object and immediately call `save`, and `afterSave` would be called.

Comment: @GoGoCarl the reason `after_save` doesn't work is that `paid_amount` is not a db attribute of `Item`, it's simply something I can access (because of `attr_accessor` that the user passes via a param). So in other words if I do `@item.update_attributes({"paid_amount"=> "10"})` the callback doesn't run because nothing is actually updating

Comment: Your code above says `assign_attributes`, which is substantially different.

Comment: Eh, I take that back.  Should still work.  `update_attributes` at it's core is really just a shortcut.  Check the result of `valid?`

Comment: If you are still having issues, post the server log output of the submit, so I can see what `params` contains.  I am thinking that it is not what you are expecting in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ook I think I have the answer here, thanks for the comments. Willem is right, in the current design, I can ensure `amount_processed?` is run by using a custom validation, changing the callback to:

```
validate :amount_processed?
```

However, doing so then makes the code a bit hacky, since I'm co-opting a validation to do the work of a callback. In other words, I would have to ensure `amount_processed?` always returned true (at end of the if statement; obviously other work would be done with `paid_amount`). There are some other considerations as well looking holistically at my code.

Given that, may change the design... but this was still a very helpful exercise